# Load shared library only if dependencies are met

Tags: c, linux, windows, linker, dynamic-linking

I have an executable that is linked to two shared libraries, each of which have dependencies to system shared libraries. (In this case these are the OpenCL and CUDA runtime libraries, but this does not affect the problem)

```
     +--> libA.so  --->  libOpenCL.so (on system)
Exe -|
     +--> libB.so  --->  libcudart.so (on system)
```

`Exe`, along with `libA.so` and `libB.so` are distributed to a user. The user may not have `libOpenCL.so` and/or `libcudart.so` installed on their system.

The goal is that `Exe` should be able to launch anyways, and detect at runtime that e.g. `libA.so` could not be loaded because its dependencies are not met.

One possibility would be to make it so that `libA.so` get loaded at runtime using `dlopen()`, where it detects if loading failed.

Is it also possible to normally link `libA.so` to `Exe`, but in a way that `Exe` can still launch if `libA.so` could not be loaded? Is this possible on Linux and/or Windows platforms?

Comment: Do you build `libA` and `libB` libraries yourself or they are external?

Comment: @yugr Yes `libA` and `libB` are build along with `Exe`, with the same compiler/ABI. They could also be static, or even part of `Exe`. They are libraries mainly as a way to group their dependencies (e.g. `libB` needs multiple CUDA libraries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this, you need `dlopen`. At program load time there is no vector for error reporting other than failure to execute, nor any reasonable choice for what the symbols intended to be found in the missing library would resolve to if they lack a definition.

Comment: In case explicit dependency on potentially missing DLL is not mandatory, one can use delay loading (see my answer for details).

Comment: Indeed, your answer may be suitable to OP. Something similar might be achievable with custom library paths with dummy libraries in a fallback path, but it seems fragile.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you can link `libA` and `libB` against potentially missing DLLs in [delay-loaded mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx). This will prevent runtime system from loading DLL until your program actually calls one of its functions.

Linux doesn't have delay load functionality out of the box but you can mimic it by adding dummy wrappers for functions from `libOpenCL.so` (or `libcudart.so`) into `libA` (or `libB`). Wrappers would `dlopen` needed libraries on first call and jump to real function implementations. Such wrappers can be written by hand or generated automatically via [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so):

```
# This will generate libOpenCL.tramp.S and libOpenCL.init.c
# which need to be linked into libA.
$ implib-gen.py libOpenCL.so
```

As a result `libA` will no longer be linked directly against `libOpenCL.so` and your program will run fine unless you call functions that use OpenCL.